# Permission management in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: server, permissions, chmod

I am new to Linux and need some help with permission management on directories for groups on  ubuntu server. Permission needed for groups on directories are as show below:

[image]

As per my understanding, in Linux we can’t have these specific combinations of permissions. It seems we will need to give permission 7 (Read, Write, Execute) to the groups for all the above three scenarios:

*chmod -R 770 Directory1*

*chmod -R 770 Directory2*

*chmod -R 770 Directory3*

Is there any better approach to manage permissions specific to my scenario?

**Note**:

1. The VM is not domain joined.
2. Files in these directories will be moved in & out daily by a FTP service.

Comment: If you set permission `770` then the owner and group can do everything, and other users/groups can do nothing - not even enter the directory. However, be aware that setting permission `770` recursively will make all files executable as well.

Comment: Files that are not executables need 1 less (660) If you need more granual permissions: look at `acl`. DELETE and WRITE are the same: by emptying a file (or directory) you basically deleted its contents so there is no delete when it comes to permissions.

Comment: FYI **[this was crossposted to Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716626/permission-management-in-linux-ubuntu)**.  Pick **ONE** site between Unix&Linux and Ask Ubuntu for this post, do NOT crosspost.